# Get the name of the Focused element in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there a function in C# that can return the Name of the Focused element and display it in a text-box or something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

or you can do something  like this...

```
  using System.ComponentModel;
  using System.Data;
  using System.Drawing;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text;
  using System.Windows.Forms;
  using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
       public Form1()
       {
            InitializeComponent();            
       }

      private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {

        MessageBox.Show(GetFocusControl());
      }

      [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
      internal static extern IntPtr GetFocus();

      private string GetFocusControl()
      {
        Control focusControl = null;
        IntPtr focusHandle = GetFocus();
        if (focusHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
            focusControl = Control.FromHandle(focusHandle);
        if (focusControl.Name.ToString().Length == 0)
            return focusControl.Parent.Parent.Name.ToString();
        else
            return focusControl.Name.ToString();
      }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Missing null checks. Had this running on a background timer and sometimes it threw NRE.
Corrected line is:

`if (focusControl != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(focusControl.Name))`

instead of the second `if`. Otherwise good and very useful code.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming WinForms, you can find the active (focused) control using the [`Form.ActiveControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.activecontrol.aspx) property and get the name.

Otherwise if this is a WPF project, you could use the [`FocusManager.GetFocusedElement()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms604088%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) method to find it.

Answer (score 1):

this function will return the index of Focused control in Form

```
    private int GetIndexFocusedControl()
    {
        int ind = -1;
        foreach (Control ctr in this.Controls)
        {
            if (ctr.Focused)
            {
                ind = (int)this.Controls.IndexOf(ctr);
            }
        }
        return ind;
    }
```

when you find the index of focused control you can access this control
from control collection

```
int indexFocused = GetIndexFocusedControl();
textBox1.Text = this.Controls[indFocused].Name; // access the Name property of control
```

Comment: you can iterate and find focused control in the same way in container elements as Panel etc

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me in c#.

```
string name = ActiveForm.ActiveControl.Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found that there's a way easier way of doing this if you're not using nested controls.
You just reference

```
Form1.ActiveControl.Name
```