# Get name of focused field

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I only found some stuff about this question for C# which I did not figure out how to translate to VB.net.

I need to get the name of the input field that has the current focus, how can I do that?

Comment: WinForms, ASP.NET or WPF? Please add the appropriate tag(s)

Comment: Thanks. It does what i asked for, but since the program on it's way to this statement does other things it says the focus is on the last used element. Is there a way to exclude all other things than just textfields?

Comment: Sorry Matt, i thought i had checked winforms. At least i know i wrote it.

Comment: If none of the text boxes have focus, how would you know which one you need the name for?

Comment: Only one control can be in focus at a time, so if your TextBox has lost focus, then, well, it's no longer in focus. You could use the `GotFocus` and `LostFocus` events to keep track of this manually.

Comment: @StevenDoggart, if none of them has focus it will do just nothing.

Comment: I'm confused.  I thought you said that the text box you were interested was no longer in service, yet you still wanted to do something with it.  Please clarify what you mean.

Comment: Take a look at this previous post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625361/get-the-name-of-the-focused-element-in-c-sharp