# C# - How to determine which element has focus?

Tags: c#, winforms, focus

Is there a way in C# to determine which Form element currently has focus?
If change VerticalScroll is focus on null?

Comment: What kind of application ? winform WPF or ASP.Net ?

Comment: read this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625361/get-the-name-of-the-focused-element-in-c-sharp

Comment: Metro? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? Windows Phone? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Form's `ActiveControl` property to **get** or **set** the currently ActiveControl.

```
this.ActiveControl = textBox1;

var myControl = this.ActiveControl;
if(myControl != null)
{
   label1.Text = "Currently active control is: "  + myControl.Name;
}
```

Comment: OP asked how to _find_ it, not _set_ it.

Comment: he can do it with ActiveControl. `Returns the control that has the focus. ` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa267252(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: Of course.  But that isn't the answer you gave.

Comment: @Selman22, Correct your answer as mentioned in comment.