# How to access to current DataGridView dynamically

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I'll try to be clear :)
I am creating new `DataGridView` dynamically thanks to a button.

It works fine, but then I want to be able to change the value of one cell of a `DataGridView` and update my database.
The problem is that I do not find how to get the current focused `DataGridView`.

I tried to play with the code in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625361/get-the-name-of-the-focused-element-in-c-sharp), I get the name of the current `DataGridView`.
But I don't think I can manipulate a control as a `DataGridView`.
Here is my function :

```
private void dataGridView_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView datagridcell = new DataGridView();
    string codearticle = "'" + CodeArticle0.Text + "'";
    string division = "'" + Division0.Text + "'";
    string colonne = datagridcell.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderText;
    string valeur = sender.ToString();
    string Ligne = datagridcell.Rows[0].Cells[3].ToString();
    Controller.ControllerMenuPrincipal.updateQALigneFab(codearticle, division, 
        colonne, valeur, Ligne);
}
```

Instead of this :

```
DataGridView datagridcell = new DataGridView();
```

I want to access the current/focused datagridview

I do not know if it is possible, I am a noob in winforms.

thanks for the help

Comment: If you attached `dataGridView_CellValueChanged` to `CellValueChanged` of yourdynamic grids, then the `sender` parameter is the `DataGridView` which the event is fired for it. So you can get the sender `DataGridView` this way: `var grid = (DataGridView)sender;`.

Comment: Thank you ! this is exactly what i needed.

Comment: Don't post the solution as part of the question. Post it as an answer. Also add some description in answer, don't post code only answers.

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. It's still there in the revision history so you can get it and add it as an answer - with explanation.

Comment: yh sorry i'm not used to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**
As Reza Aghaei said,

> " If you attached dataGridView_CellValueChanged to CellValueChanged of yourdynamic grids, then the sender parameter is the DataGridView which the event is fired for it. So you can get the sender DataGridView this way: var grid = (DataGridView)sender;. – Reza Aghaei"

so i just replaced this line :

```
DataGridView datagridcell = new DataGridView();
```

by this one:

```
var grid = (DataGridView)sender;
```

so i can use "grid" variable  to manipulate my current datagridview

final code looks like that :

```
        private void dataGridView13_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        var grid = (DataGridView)sender; //get current datagridview
        string codearticle = "'" + CodeArticle0.Text + "'";
        string division = "'" + Division0.Text + "'";
        string colonne = grid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderText; //get column headertext of current cell 
        string valeur = grid[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString(); //get new value of current cell
        string Ligne = grid[3, 0].Value.ToString(); 
        Controller.ControllerMenuPrincipal.updateQALigneFab(codearticle, division, colonne, valeur, Ligne); //calling stored procedure to update my table
    }
```